# How can I fill up missing object parameters in an elegant way?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

I am having trouble using initial parameters (I am not sure if there is a typescript solution or it is just a JavaScript question, so I present you the Javascript equivalent to you):

```
const helloWorldWithOptions = (options = { a:1, b:2 } ) => {
  console.log("Hello World!")
};
```

When using the function:

```
helloWorldWithOptions( {a:4} );
```

Typescript says that I am missing the object key `b` when using the function. What I would expect is that js/ts filling up the missing values with the initial parameters. If there is already a state of the art, let me know.

Comment: You can make `b` optional: `const helloWorldWithOptions=(options: { a: number; b?: number; } = {a: 1, b: 2})=>{console.log("Hello World!")}`

Comment: The comment above explains it perfectly. Just make the parameter optional with the ? option flag.

Comment: @tromgy this doesn't seem to solve my problem: when I use your function with only one "sub-parameter" `helloWorldWithOptions({a:5})` the sub-parameter b won't be filled up by the default paramter, so can't be accessed

Comment: @bc4, ah, yes you're correct. The default only would apply if the `options` argument is completely missing. Then you need to make the default object  "explicit" and merge it inside the function, similar to what @AKX did in his answer. Here's the [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgUwGYEMCuAbKEYF4YDeKAXDAIwA0MARqQEwC+A3AFAuiSwAWCGGIAdRAAnDHAEBLKFwDyABygTwEXAAoQCpZFIEYJGGDQBbagmFMaAflKGTZiwzzxk6LBACUeAHyEWMfzAc0DDCCCgY8orKTroAdPGIqJjYVPGxGlGQMAx+AUEgGAix-ADmqgAGABK8-DAAJASh4ZFaELEojihgcPWNYRGayrHUDOXurDksPHyCImKS0i3KquNs0-xCouJSsoOQqkSkAMwM7kA).

Comment: @tromgy thanks for your answer. I am just trying to find an implementation, that doesn't need the use of an extra merging line and still looks "appealing" to the eye. But I think, there isn't any yet

Comment: @bc4, if you really want to avoid explicit merging, you can use destructuring with defaults instead: `const helloWorldWithOptions = ({ a, b = 2 } : { a: number; b?: number} = { a: 1}) => {....`.

Comment: Another [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAFgUwDZJAdRAJyQEzQSyjgHkAHKfcCGAXhgAoBvGAQwBoYAjWmAJgF8YALhjMWIsAFcAtpwSYOnAPwSZczILqNxMAIz8AlLQB8ogFAxLMUJBBIEAOlQBzegAMAEslQwAJNsEWMBw-Rk5+NwMAbjN+MzMAegSYYgAleJtoeG90LFwCIjIKKl4eJlYeXUUeUsERMRUYKVl5KK5G5vVNUUMTcytrKjtHF3cvFBAYKBBJ-xZA4NDwyJi4s0QJjGw8QhJySkh6aPiN1C383aKDiCYdAGZDGMTkgBU4fGoAd3AAclhQaSkfD2GAAWgqHxgmAQAEdJPhoTgRKdctsCntiocwiIACyPE45c47Qr7Ki3EQAVkUIgAbPjnmDQUzmcyCZs8sSMddeEcniiieiriVyTAHsd1oSOYLSZAediYHjxfypZcZRA5ToqVxafT4kA)

Comment: this seems to kinda solve my problem, except I can't index my "options" parameter anymore (because I would like to pass my options parameter to another function in helloWordWithOptions). I tried something with the "as" key-word, but this did not work either. I think, I will need to use the answer by @AKK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [the `Partial` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype) and [`...` spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals) to combine your defaults with the caller's overrides.

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgUwGYEMCuAbKEYF4YDeMKAXDAIwA0MARmQEwwC+A3AFBsD0nMAwiJjgw0EBMRhgUAWwRCoATwAOYgJaQoCFEJBIYAAwXKd8ZOiwQ9MKCBAA6NqHUwAFggwYQAdRAAnDHE8VKGcAeUUoFXAcfAAKEHDIyDIABRQfCJQMAB5DBGNEVExsAD48QiYASjxSgjYYGEdoGBkfAHNZMIiosqJbPoKzbGo+23iuyGZ2esaQDARbD1aYlva4TsSICvZWNld3L19-QOD1qJiiUhgAZmYttiA)

```
const defaults = { a: 1, b: 2 };

// Could use a named type instead of `typeof defaults` too.
const helloWorldWithOptions = (options: Partial<typeof defaults> = {}) => {
  const mergedOptions = { ...defaults, ...options };
  console.log(mergedOptions);
};
helloWorldWithOptions({ a: 3 });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer: This is what I was looking for. But what I am specifically aiming for, is to get lost of the first line of your function definition `const mergedOptions = { ...defaults, ...options };` too. But I don't think, that there is an implementation for this functionality yet

Answer (score 1):

You can specify default values whenever you declare a function:

```
function aFunction({a = 1, b = 2}) {console.log(a, b)}

aFunction({}) //prints "1 2"
```

in this case, 'aFunction' receives an object, and whenever you call the function with an empty object, it automatically fills the blank fields.
Alternatively, you can call 'aFunction' with the parameters you want, for example:

```
aFunction({a: 2, b: 3}) //prints "2 3"
```

Comment: I would like to just use `aFunction({a:5})` and b will be automaticly filled up with 2 as declared in the default parameter

Comment: i called `aFunction({a: 5})` and the result was `'5 2'`. It worked for me using the answer I gave you

Comment: what interpreter are you using? For my specific project, I am using ts-node v10.4.0 which itself uses node v16.13.2. (ts-node "compiles" in run-time the ts-files to js files)

Comment: well, for this example case i used the console on my browser. I´m currently using the latest Chrome version. However, unless is a typescript "problem" (with I don´t think it is), you should be able to get the same results as I do.

Comment: I am sorry to say so, but I am not getting the same results. I might inform you, if something changes with this approach. But thanks for your effort so far